# Notation of the Pullback of a $1$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega = \mathrm{d}y-A(t,y)\,\mathrm{d}t$ and $\gamma(t)=(t,y(t))^t$ be given.  I want to compute $\gamma^*\omega(t)=\omega_{\gamma(t)}(\dot\gamma(t))$.

Now the actual problem I have, is to understand the notation of the pullback. In my script the definition of the pullback of a $k$-form by $\Phi$

$\alpha=\sum_{1\le l_1<...<l_k\le N}\alpha^{l_1...l_k}\,\mathrm{d}y_{l_1}\wedge ... \wedge\mathrm{d}y_{l_k} $

on an $N$-dimensional manifold is given by

$\Phi^*\alpha=\sum_{1\le l_1<...<l_k\le N}(\Phi^*\alpha^{l_1...l_k})\,\mathrm{d}\Phi_{l_1}\wedge ... \wedge\mathrm{d}\Phi_{l_k} $

which is pretty self-explanatory. I just don't understand what is meant by the first pullback notation given.

When I use the definition of a $k$-form I get

$\gamma^*\omega(t)=\dot \gamma (t)\,\mathrm{d}t - A(t,\gamma(t))\,\mathrm{d}t$

But what is meant by $\omega_{\gamma(t)}(\dot\gamma(t))$?

Comment: It is the invariant definition of pullback of a covector field. What is you pointed out from your script is the coordinate expression of pullback.

Comment: But how can I use the invariant definition? The problem is, this definition, does not even show up as definition in my script. It's only defined as coordinate expression. I am unsure of what this even means.

Comment: Choose a chart on the interest point $\gamma(t) \in M$ , then compute $\gamma^*\omega(t) = \omega_{\gamma(t)} (\dot{\gamma}(t)) = (\omega_i(\gamma(t)) dx^i)(\dot{\gamma}^j(t) \partial_j) = \omega_i(\gamma(t)) \dot{\gamma}^j(t)( dx^i) (\partial_j) =  \omega_i(\gamma(t)) \dot{\gamma}^j(t) \delta^i_j = \omega_i(\gamma(t)) \dot{\gamma}^i(t)$.

Comment: What you're trying to prove is wrong. The pullback of $\omega$ is still a $1$-form. But your right-hand side is a number for each value of $t$: You're evaluating the $1$-form $\omega$ at the point $\gamma(t)$ and applying it to a tangent vector.